# How to retrieve SlingHttpServletRequest from ResourceResolver

Tags: integration-testing, aem, sling

I would like to retrieve the request used to resolve the resources I retrieve from the ResourceResolver.

I am performing integration testing using [Teleporter Rule](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/org-apache-sling-junit-bundles.html#the-teleporterrule) And can resolve the resource but can't find its corresponding request.

```
@Rule
    public final TeleporterRule teleporter = TeleporterRule.forClass(getClass(), "Launchpad");

    @Test
    public void testPage() throws LoginException {
        ResourceResolverFactory resourceResolverFactory = teleporter.getService(ResourceResolverFactory.class);
        ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
        Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource("/content/test/en");
        PageModel page = resource.adaptTo(PageModel.class);
    }
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the request like I can with my unit tests using SlingContext.

```
SlingContextImpl slingContext = new SlingContextImpl();
slingContext.currentResource("/content/test/en");
slingContext.request()
```

I would like to retrieve the request like I can with my unit tests and properly test my sling models that inject the request.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand teleporter tests run in the context of the OSGi container but don't directly expose requests/responses. Since there are no HTTP requests involved, there is nothing to adapt to.